# return items from one list if not in the other

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I want to return the items from `Project` if that project does not appear in my task list, `Task`. My code only returns everything and in `Project`. What am I doing wrong?

```
Task = [['Task1','Project1',3],['Task2','Project4',6]]
Project = [['Project1', 'Andrew'],['Project2','Bob'],['Project3','Bob']]

not_in_list = [item for item in Project if item[0] not in Case]

print not_in_list
```

Output:

```
[['Project1', 'Andrew'], ['Project2', 'Bob'], ['Project3', 'Bob']]
```

Expected Result:

```
[['Project2', 'Bob'],['Project3', 'Bob']]
```

Comment: Where does `Case` come from?

Comment: Does the Project name always show up in the same position in the list of Tasks?

Comment: A list of pairs like `[['Project1', 'Andrew'],['Project2','Bob'],['Project3','Bob']]` looks like a good candidate for a dict. In fact the dict constructor accepts a list of `(key, value)`.

Comment: @PauloScardine Right, but won't help here probably. It would go into the wrong direction...

Comment: @glglgl: I would make both lists dictionaries having "projects" as keys. At the  first dict values should be a list of tasks+attributes, and on the second dict, a list of members for each project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
Task = [['Task1','Project1',3],['Task2','Project4',6]]
Project = [['Project1', 'Andrew'],['Project2','Bob'],['Project3','Bob']]

no_tasks = [p for p in Project if all(p[0] not in t for t in Task)]
print no_tasks
```

but will be horribly inefficient for large lists. Time to reconsider your data structure!

Answer (score 0):

Only slightly more efficient than the previous answer, if you can assume Project name is always in index 1 of Task:

```
>>> Task = [['Task1','Project1',3],['Task2','Project4',6]]
>>> Project = [['Project1', 'Andrew'],['Project2','Bob'],['Project3','Bob']]
>>> assigned = [t[1] for t in Task]
>>> [p for p in Project if p[0] not in assigned]
[['Project2', 'Bob'], ['Project3', 'Bob']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
task = [['Task1','Project1',3],['Task2','Project4',6]]
project = [['Project1', 'Andrew'],['Project2','Bob'],['Project3','Bob']]
task_projects = set(pr for _, pr, _ in task)

not_in_list = [item for item in project if item[0] not in task_projects]

print not_in_list
```

(Note that I changed the variable names so that they match the recommendations.)

This code first creates a set of project names present. Checking for existence of an item in a set is much cheaper than in a list.